# Using amazon SES to send email in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, cdo.message

I'm trying to send a test email with Amazon SES but to no luck:

```
Dim iMsg, iConf, Flds
Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

Set Flds = iConf.Fields

Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2

With Flds
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort 
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic 
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "ABCDE"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "12345"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 10
.Update
End With

With iMsg
Set .Configuration = iConf
.To = "bar@foo.com"
.From = "foo@bar.com"
.Subject = "test"
.TextBody = "body"
.Send
End With

response.write("sent")
```

Logging information seems to suggest something wrong with authentication. Unfortunately, I'm not well versed and don't understand what I might be doing wrong.

```
Response: 250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
Response: 250-8BITMIME
Response: 250-SIZE 10485760
Response: 250-STARTTLS
Response: 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
Response: 250 Ok

Command: AUTH LOGIN

Response: 530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Command: MAIL FROM: [address in verified senders list]

Response: 530 Authentication required

Command: Quit
```

Comment: How did you get that log information from VBScript/CDO?

Comment: @ulty4life I think it was with Wireshark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is in the following:

> Response: 530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

You need to enable a secure connection before you authenticate. You have already *enabled* SSL through your configuration:

```
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
```

Change this to:

```
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
```

(notice the change from `True` to `1`)

Comment: I tried that and got this: `Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'

Object doesn't support this property or method: 'EnableSsl'`

Comment: Okay, don't add the `.EnableSsl = True` option then. I think I am confusing .NET with ASP Classic. But do change `True` to `1` for the `smtpusessl` configuration option.

Comment: Seems to have worked. Can't believe it came down to that. Cheers!

Comment: Sometimes it can be this simple. Great it worked out for you!